# RegexQuiz - Task 19 - matching entity

Tags: regex

I try to solve the quiz at http://www.regex101.com/quiz/ and got stuck with six remaining task.

## Task #19

> In an HTML page, replace the text **`micro`** with ***`&micro;`***. Oh, and
>   don't screw up the code: don't replace inside **`<the tags>`** or **`&entities;`**

My current attempt is this sweet regex:

`/(?<=\G|>)([^<>]*?<?)(?:(?<=[^\w&#]|^)(?=[\w#]*)micro(?=[\w#]*;)|micro(?![\w#]*;))(?(?<=<micro)(?!>))/gm`

It can be tested here: http://www.regex101.com/r/zG2pD3

#### And here is the question:

> Test 16 of 28 failed: It's matching **`micro`** inside an entity.

I can't follow this statement. In my tests are many entities, and none of them is matched. Can someone explain what happens and/or what entity is meant?

Also strange: [RegexQuiz - Task 20 - matching csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176915/regexquiz-task-20-matching-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, did it, Test 16 fails no longer.

The failing entity was `&asdmicroasd ;`. I'm confused of spaces inside of entities... well, this regex does it... but no another test fails ^^

`/(?<=\G|>)([^<>]*?<?)(?:(?<=[^\w&#\s]|^)(?=[\w#\s]*)micro(?=[\w#\s]*;)|micro(?![\w#\s]*;))(?(?<=<micro)(?!>))/gm`

#### edit

finished the Task... I wont to spoil the solution. If someone needs help, please contact me.

Well, here's the result when finishing the task with useful recommendation to avoid parsing HTML via regex

> Correct. Just keep in mind you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. Here's a link that describes why: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html