# RegexQuiz - Task 20 - matching csv

Tags: regex

I try to solve the quiz at http://www.regex101.com/quiz/ and got stuck with six remaining task.

## Task #20

> In a comma separated list, backreference all elements. Moreover, an item can be enclosed in quotes and, inside quotes, a backslash escapes a character. Spaces around each element must be trimmed. Example: **`one,"item two" , "item \"three\"" , "and, finally, the fourth"`**

My current attempt is this sweet regex:

`/(?:^|\G)\s*"?((?<=")(?:\\.|[^\n"\\])*(?=")|(?<!")[^\n",]+(?<!\s))"?\s*(?:,|$)/gm`

It can be tested here: http://www.regex101.com/r/mH6rB2

#### And here is the question:

> Test 15 of 27 failed: If one item starts with a quote, it should be closed. And if there's an item with unbalanced quotes, your pattern should not match that item nor anything else from that point. For example, you shouldn't match: **`"this_item,should,not,match`**

I tested exactly against the given string (**`"this_item,should,not,match`**) (see the link above) and it doesn't match. What wants the test to tell me?!

Also strange: [RegexQuiz - Task 19 - matching entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176856/regexquiz-task-19-matching-entity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the quiz, no longer an answer is needed, the regex above is the solution.